# How to increase hit area of div?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, visibility

I need to create an area on-screen that is interactive, with the hit area larger than the interactive element.  However, I don't want the hit area to impact the DOM layout.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vzJb/13/) demonstrates what I'm after.  A DOM inspector shows that `#hitArea` extends above and below `#content`, but it's not interactive because it's clipped by its parent element, `#container`, with `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out as I was writing up the question, so I'm documenting it here.

`overflow:hidden` clips the interactive area (aka "hit area") as well as the visible area, so it's defeating the purpose here.  Commenting out `overflow:hidden` and setting `background-color: none` on `#hitArea` allows the hit area to extend beyond the visible bounds of the element (`#content`).

http://jsfiddle.net/5vzJb/14/

In my case, I need to clip the content, so I can apply `overflow:hidden` to `#content` instead, and append my content as divs within `#content`.